# Convert double asterisk to bold tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to turn `**test**` into `<b>test</b>`

I've tried:

```js
const result = "**str**".replace(/\*/g, "<b>");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```js
const result = "**str**".replace(/\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}/g, "<b>$1</b>");
console.log(result);
```